# Dynamic Text Boxes disappearing in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dynamic, textbox, frame

I've got a small interactive flash animation, there's a button that allows the user to gain points then clicked, then another to go to a "Shop" when clicked. the only problem is that the Dynamic text box doesn't show the value on the second frame. All the actionscript is on one Layer, throughout the entire file.

```
var money = 100;
var shopbtn;
cash_txt.text = money;

stop();

Button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, MoneyGet);
function MoneyGet (evt: MouseEvent){
money += 50;
cash_txt.text = money;
}

shopbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Shop);
function Shop (evt: MouseEvent){
cash_txt.text = money;
gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

I've checked if embedded fonts is working, and it's fine. Thanks.
I'm using Professional CC.

Comment: logic is wrong in your setup. In the second frame is there a textfield instance named cash_txt? If you can send your fla i can check

Comment: Yes, the second frame simply has the First text box with an instance name of cash_txt.

Comment: did you embeded the font in dynamic text field?

Comment: Yes, embedded the font...